# How to increase height navigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

I have a navigationBar. But i need to increase the height of navigationBar. I try to this code below, But It's not working.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,66.0)];
```

Please help me another solution. Thanks you for any supporting!

Comment: it's working or it's not working?...

Comment: i have update my question. Thanks you for remind me!

Comment: You cannot change the height of a navigation controller's navigation bar. Give up the whole idea.

Comment: Agree with matt, its not changeable, but you can hide the bar itself, and use another custom view as the bar, then it will solve your problem